# Postgres Transcendent Index Usage Though the Function Call

Tags: postgresql

If we have a tabled with an indexed fields

```
create table A (
...
 indexed_field integer
...
);

create index on A(indexed_field);

create or replace function refer_indexed_table(...other_criterion)
    returns table (
     ...
    ) as
$func$
begin
    return query
    select
        *
    from A
    where other_fields match other_criterion;
end
$func$ language plpgsql;

select * from refer_indexed_table(whatever)
where refer_indexed_table.indexed_field = 54;
```

Would this refer to an `indexed_field` through the function call still profit from existing index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  That would require the function body to be "inlined" and currently that might happen only with `language SQL` functions.